# Remove items from combo box lwuit?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-combobox

How to remove all items or a single item from a combo box in LWUIT ?

Is there any functions like `removeall()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `getModel().removeItem(index)` and remove the item's from `ComboBox`. See the sample code,

```
ComboBox c = new ComboBox(vector); // you can use ListModel or String[] instead of vector

// for remove single item in combobox
c.getModel().removeItem(index); // pass the removable index number
```

If you want to remove all item means set the empty `ListModel` on `combobox.setModel(model)` or pass the empty `Vector` on `ComboBox` constructor.

Comment: Thanks Bharath, you saved my day. I missed the getModel() part :ashamed:

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the all the items from combobox in lwuit,sample code given below:

```
ListModel listModel=dayCombo.getModel();

int size_of_previous_day=listModel.getSize();
for(int i=0;i<size_of_previous_day;i++)
    listModel.removeItem(0);
dayCombo.setModel(listModel);
```

Comment: should the .removeItem(0) have .removeItem(i)?